# insertSubview:belowSubview still places view above swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I'm trying to make a segue in my app such that the current view slides away to reveal a view below it.

This is my code:

```
let window = UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window!
window?.insertSubview(destinationView, belowSubview: sourceView)
destinationView.center = CGPoint(x: sourceView.center.x, y: sourceView.center.y)

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.6, animations: {
    sourceView.center = CGPoint(x: sourceView.center.x, y: 0 - sourceView.center.y)
}, completion: { (value: Bool) in
    self.source.navigationController?.pushViewController(self.destination, animated: false)
})
```

However, the view that I'm segueing to simply appears over the top of the view I'm currently on. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I solved it. Here was my solution in case anyone else has this problem:

```
window?.insertSubview(destinationView, belowSubview: sourceView)
window?.insertSubview(sourceView, aboveSubview: destinationView)
```

I just added that second line of code and it worked.